# No such file or directory - ./log/acts_as_ferret.log (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i try to execute a functional test with this command

```
 ruby -I. supplier_controller_test.rb
```

now the code:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../test_helper' 
require 'admin/supplier_controller' 

# Re-raise errors caught by the controller.   
class Admin::SupplierController; def rescue_action(e) raise e end; end  

class Admin::SupplierControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  fixtures :suppliers

 def setup   
    @controller = Admin::SupplierController.new  
    @request = ActionController::TestRequest.new  
    @response = ActionController::TestResponse.new  
 end  

 def test_new
   get :new  
   assert_template 'admin/supplier/new'  
   assert_tag 'h1', :content => 'Create new supplier'  
   assert_tag 'form', :attributes => {:action => '/admin/supplier/create'}   
 end  
end
```

this is the error that i get

```
 No such file or directory - ./log/acts_as_ferret.log (Errno::ENOENT)
```

It's supposed that should exists an acts_as_ferret.log?

Answer (score 0):

When you run  `ruby -I . path_to_code` with the -I option you are supplying the directory to load libraries from.

From the error it looks like you are trying to load a log/acts_as_ferret.log from the directory that you just specified.

Is it possible that you want to be using a different directory?

Comment: if I use `ruby path to code` it gives the same error.

Comment: Alright I think you still might need the -I option when you are trying to run this. What is that acts_as_ferret log being used for? I assume just writing some output to?

Comment: I dont know what act_as_ferret.log is, i haven't created it

Comment: How i can put the path of acts_as_ferret.log in the command ruby -I path_of _file?

Comment: Something is searchinf for ./log/acts_as_ferret.log but this file is in /../../log/acts_as_ferret.log ,two directories above but i don't know what i have to do to make it find the file.

Comment: So the first argument that you are passing after the -I is the directory that you want to be searching for libraries in. So your command my look like ruby -I ../../ path_to_ruby_file.rb and then off you go.